# How to open a gzip file using fopen (or a function with the same return value as fopen) in C++?

Tags: c++, compression, gzip, fopen

I currently have some code reading files which are not compressed, it uses the following approach to read a file in C++

```
FILE* id = fopen("myfile.dat", "r");
```

after obtaining *id*, different parts of the code access the file using *fread*, *fseek*, etc.

I would like to adapt my code so as to open a gzip version of the file, e.g. "myfile.dat.gz" without needing to change too much.

Ideally I would implement a wrapper to fopen, call it fopen2, which can read both myfile.dat and myfile.dat.gz, i.e. it should return a pointer to a FILE object, so that the remaining of the code does not need to be changed.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

PS: it would be fine to decompress the whole file in memory, if this approach provides a solution

Comment: I think you're looking for [something along the lines of zlib](http://www.zlib.net/).

Comment: You'd use [zlib](http://zlib.net/) for uncompression business. Using a `FILE*` won't work, at least not portably. If you had used IOStreams it _might_ have been possible to create a wrapper (I haven't looked at zlib's seeking interface too closely).

Comment: from a first look it seems that the most portable solution would be to use zlib to create a new temporary uncompressed file, store it somewhere, and then use the legacy code to read it, and finally remove the temporary file. Looks as quite some overhead... I was hoping to find a more portable solution...

Comment: Google "c++ iostream gzip uncompress filter". Boost does this really well.

Comment: well, also here I have the problem of not getting a FILE object

Comment: You probably should consider re-writng the interface for that functionalit such that it uses `streams` instead of `FILE*` - even if you don't do that right now, I'd raise it as a "maintenance defect that needs to be fixed eventually". There are so many ways that a stream interface will help - you can even write a stream interface that operates on `FILE*` if you like.

Comment: good suggestion, do you think there is some performance penalization if I use streams instead of FILE*?  I have to read files as fast as possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[zlib](http://zlib.net/) provides analogs of `fopen()`, `fread()`, etc. called `gzopen()`, `gzread()`, etc. for reading and writing gzip files. If the file is not gzip-compressed, it will be read just as the `f` functions would. So you would only need to change the function names and link in zlib.